# How would I push the button to the bottom of the CSS flexbox in such case?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have created multiple CSS flexboxes on this landing page and I would like to have the SELECT button to be always on the bottom of each box, no matter the size of textual content above. I tried to use multiple properties such as `align-self`, `justify-content`, `align-items`, `align-text` with various attributes but could not achieve the desired outcome.

Would could I possibly do in this situation to make it work?

Here is the screenshot of flexboxes:
[image]

Here is my HTML and CSS for this section:

```css
#pricing-option-1, #pricing-option-2, #pricing-option-3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pricing-amount {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="pricing-option-2">
        <h3 class="pricing-option-header">BASIC ENBALI</h3>
        <p class="pricing-amount">$1200/month</p>
        <div class="pricing-body">
          <p class="pricing-option-description">The most popular option. You wouldn't need to worry about finding a place to live, commute to the classes, cooking or find a right place to eat. We got you!</p>
          <ul class="pricing-option-bulletpoints">
            <li>80 hours of any classes</li>
            <li>Accommodation on campus (4 people per room)</li>
            <li>Meal plan (3 times a day)</li>
            <li>Unlimited access to our library</li>
            <li>Unlimited access to our online courses library</li>
          </ul> 
        </div>
        <p class="select-option">
            <button type="submit">SELECT</button>
        </p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a defined height for the container to avoid that the height adjusts to the contents (I added that in the snippet below, and I erased some of the contents to make it more obvious).

Then you can apply `margin-top: auto;` to the last element (the container for the button) wo automatically move that to the bottom (end of the flex order)

```css
#pricing-option-1,
#pricing-option-2,
#pricing-option-3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pricing-amount {
  background-color: blue;
}

#pricing-option-2 {
  height: 500px;
}
.v {
   margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="pricing-option-2">
  <h3 class="pricing-option-header">BASIC ENBALI</h3>
  <p class="pricing-amount">$1200/month</p>
  <div class="pricing-body">
    <p class="pricing-option-description">The most popular option. place to eat. We got you!</p>
    <ul class="pricing-option-bulletpoints">
      <li>80 hours of any classes</li>
      <li>Accommodation on campus (4 people per room)</li>
      <li>Unlimited access to our online courses library</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p class=" v">
    <button type="submit">SELECT</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: @PeterDvukhrechensky As I wrote: to avoid that the height adjusts to the contents

Comment: I understand that, but why? What if the content takes more than the height value?

Comment: @PeterDvukhrechensky depends: If you set `flex-wrap`, it will wrap into a second column, if you use `overflow: visible`, it will grow, if you do nothing, a scrollbar will appear. But that's not part of the question – the image in the question shows elements of equal height, some of would be less high if no height were set. Since the OP marked my answer as accepted, I seem to have been right about height and margin-top: auto

Answer (score -1):

1. First make the *.pricing-body* block to be a flexbox.
2. Then set **flex-grow: 1** on *.select-option* which will make it fill all of the free space
3. Finally align the content of *.select-option* with **align-items: flex-end** to keep the button to the bottom

Just add this piece of code to your CSS:

```
.pricing-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.select-option {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

[See this codepen example](https://codepen.io/stpetr/pen/rNVNGJz)